# Wrapfigure with caption and floatfoot problem

Tags: floats, captions, wrapfigure

I'm currently writing my master thesis and I face some problems with wraping pictures and large captions/ floatfoot. I use the package "Floatrow and Floatsetup".
Here is the problem : I have too big floatfoot for my pictures and thus when wraping the picture some white spaces appear and my floatnote goes beyond the vertical limit of the page.

I would like to keep the picture wrapped around the text (to avoid any loose of space) and make the caption and the floatnote take the whole textwidth (instead of the same width as the picture) with rules like in this picture below (made with microsoft word). NB : the bottom rule should have appeared as well.

[image: Ideal situation]

Here is my actual code :

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[wrapfigure]{style=ruled,capposition=bottom,footposition=bottom}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ABCmod} 
\end{center}
\caption{Baba general structure}\label{fig:abc}
\floatfoot{babababababababababababababababababababbbaabbabaababbababaababbaabababbabaabababababababababababbabaababababbababaababababbabababababaababababababababababababababababababababababababbababababbabababbababbababababbababababbabababababbababababababababbababababbababababababbabababababababbababababababababbababababababababababbababababababababbababababababababbababab}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{hscale=0.85,vscale=0.85,centering}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[wrapfigure]{style=ruled,capposition=bottom,footposition=bottom}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\begin{document}
Most of the ABC transporters are ATP-dependent transmembrane proteins. Proteins, ions, amino acids or sugars can effectively travel against their concentration gradients thanks to an alternating acces model caused by conformational changes consequent to ATP binding in the NBD and substrate fixation on the TMD. The transport of substrates draws its driving force from the hydrolysis of ATP which defines them as active transporters. However, the precise mechanism is still misunderstood as no fully high-resolution of a complete ABC protein ATP-cycle has been achieved. The ABC family is divided into importers (almost exclusively prokaryots) and exporters. The difference between them lies in the variety of membrane-spanning-domains (MSD) as the NBDs are more structurally conserved. These observations witness the diversity of substrates/ TMD couplings specific to each transporter and support the hypothesis of a universal ATP hydrolysis mechanism by the NBDs.
\\
NBDs contain a Walker A motif (P-loop) and a Walker B motif separated by a C-signature sequence (LSGGQ) which is the specific and conserved sequence of ABC proteins. The dimerization of NBDs make a head-to-tail conformation with interaction between the Walker motifs of one NBD and the signature sequence of the other. Other features commonly found in ABC proteins are the A-, D-, Q- and H-loops.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ABCmod} 
\end{center}
\caption{ABC transporters general structure}\label{fig:abc}
\floatfoot{Most of the ABC transporters are ATP-dependent transmembrane proteins. Proteins, ions, amino acids or sugars can effectively travel against their concentration gradients thanks to an alternating acces model caused by conformational changes consequent to ATP binding in the NBD and substrate fixation on the TMD. The transport of substrates draws its driving force from the hydrolysis of ATP which defines them as active transporters}
\end{wrapfigure}
\\
ABC proteins are widely studied firstly due to their involvement in many physiological roles such as metabolites transport, signal transduction, protein secretion or antigen presentation. Secondly, because these proteins are involved in many human diseases both directly (mostly caused by mutations) and indirectly with their role in bacterial anti-drug resistance and chemotherapy failure.  
\end {document}
```

Comment: You *need* this specific setup? Why would you have the text flow *break* across the caption? That is, have a figure caption spanning the full text width causing a disjoint in the flow of the regular (wrapping) text. One can probably achieve this, but it will take quite some *manual* code to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Werner, actually I came with this setup because my captions were too big and didn't fit in only half width of the page below the picture. So i thought it might be better in order to save space and prevent any problems with the captions to make a full width caption. But any solution ensuring that the picture and the caption below can fit in one page height are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Something this complicated requires manually wrapping the text.  The `\nopar` macro is useful for this, but was not needed for this MWE.  Also, narrow columns are normally formatted using `\sloppy`.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks, 12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{hscale=0.85,vscale=0.85,centering}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[wrapfigure]{style=ruled,capposition=bottom,footposition=bottom}
%\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\nopar}{\bgroup\parfillskip=0pt\par\egroup}% insert to manually break a paragraph

\newcommand{\boxcaption}[2][\empty]% same as \caption
{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\par
  \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \abovecaptionskip=0pt
  \belowcaptionskip=0pt
  \captionof{figure}[#1]{#2}
  \end{minipage}}%
\vspace{\belowcaptionskip}\par}

\edef\normalparindent{\the\parindent}

\begin{document}
Most of the ABC transporters are ATP-dependent transmembrane proteins. Proteins, ions, amino acids or sugars can effectively travel against their concentration gradients thanks to an alternating acces model caused by conformational changes consequent to ATP binding in the NBD and substrate fixation on the TMD. The transport of substrates draws its driving force from the hydrolysis of ATP which defines them as active transporters. However, the precise mechanism is still misunderstood as no fully high-resolution of a complete ABC protein ATP-cycle has been achieved. The ABC family is divided into importers (almost exclusively prokaryots) and exporters. The difference between them lies in the variety of membrane-spanning-domains (MSD) as the NBDs are more structurally conserved. These observations witness the diversity of substrates/ TMD couplings specific to each transporter and support the hypothesis of a universal ATP hydrolysis mechanism by the NBDs.

NBDs contain a Walker A motif (P-loop) and a Walker B motif separated by a C-signature sequence (LSGGQ) which is the specific and conserved sequence of ABC proteins. The dimerization of NBDs make a head-to-tail conformation with interaction between the Walker motifs of one NBD and the signature sequence of the other. Other features commonly found in ABC proteins are the A-, D-, Q- and H-loops.

\noindent\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image} 
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
\parindent=\normalparindent\relax
ABC proteins are widely studied firstly due to their involvement in many physiological roles such as metabolites transport, signal transduction, protein secretion or antigen presentation. Secondly, because these proteins are involved in many human diseases both directly (mostly caused by mutations) and indirectly with their role in bacterial anti-drug resistance and chemotherapy failure.
\end{minipage}}

\boxcaption{ABC transporters general structure --
Most of the ABC transporters are ATP-dependent transmembrane proteins. Proteins, ions, amino acids or sugars can effectively travel against their concentration gradients thanks to an alternating acces model caused by conformational changes consequent to ATP binding in the NBD and substrate fixation on the TMD. The transport of substrates draws its driving force from the hydrolysis of ATP which defines them as active transporters}
\label{fig:abc}

\end {document}
```

[image: full page]